# Excel - Match 2 columns and paste result from appending cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-match, excel-2008

From the table below, I want to match 'COLUMN A' and 'COLUMN C', when the match happens, the value from 'COLUMN D' should be pasted in 'COLUMN B'.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C        Column D
 AB           FAST         AE            APPLE
 CD           RAINBOW      EF            BANANA
 EF           BANANA       AG            CARROT
 GH           HAMSTER      ET            DOG
                           WE            EYE
                           AB            FAST
                           GF            GOOGLE
                           GH            HAMSTER
                           HJ            JOKER
                           ER            LION
                           CD            RAINBOW
```

Expected result:

```
COL A         COL C                    COL D              COL B
'AB'  matched  'AB' extract value from 'FAST' and paste in FAST
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your table including the headers, click insert and then click table. Paste the following formula in COLUMN B `INDEX(Table1,MATCH([@[Col A]],[Col C],0),4)`